# What are the reasons for Dropwizard meter to show drop in counts?

Tags: dropwizard, metrics, graphite

I am using Dropwizard meter to monitor number of times a method is called. A Dropwizard meter among other things records the count for a metric. I assumed that a count will only go upwards, but in my particular scenario, I noticed that there were a few instances, where the counter actually goes down and them comes back up again. Why might this happen? Thanks!

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30987757/dropwizard-metrics-meters-vs-timers?rq=1 helps?

Comment: I've read that thread, but I didn't see any reason for the counter value to go down

Comment: The meter can not go down the count unless you restart your application. Can you update your code with an example on how you implemented this and how you are marking your events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across this link http://dieter.plaetinck.be/post/25-graphite-grafana-statsd-gotchas/#traffic.drop I think this is why I am seeing this drop